# handle PolicyLengthExceededException for cloud watch log streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, stream, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I'd like to stream all my AWS lambda logs to another lambda. 
Works great but I have arround 60 functions and I'm not able to add more triggers :

From lambda view :

```
An error occurred when creating the trigger: The final policy size (20902) 
is bigger than the limit (20480). (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: PolicyLengthExceededException; Request ID: def7a279-aa78-424b- 
aca8-d701363648d0)
```

From cloud watch view :

```
There was a problem
There was an error creating this subscription filter: The final policy 
size is bigger than the limit of 20480.
```

I'm trying to find the policy in question (perhaps I can update it to use wildcards) but I don't know which is used ?

Comment: An excellent question. Unfortunately, I think that the policy in question is managed within AWS and not exposed as an account-accessible policy in IAM (I've looked). My best suggestion -- which isn't great -- is to create a duplicate Lambda to handle additional subscriptions.

Comment: I was thinking about it but it's not a ideal design ! Thanks for your reply

Comment: Actually, as I was driving into work, I realized that my comment was only half-right: the policy is hidden if you create the subscription from the Console. However, if you use [the cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-subscription-filter.html), you have the option of specifying a role that controls access to the destination. I haven't tried this (so not an answer -- I've found too many edge cases with subscriptions), but have created subscriptions using CloudFormation that specified a role. Good luck.